# How can I create patch?

Tags: installation, patch

I write my programm and create setup with Visual Studio Setup Project.  Setup contains more then 100 dlls.
But sometimes I need to fix bug in 1-2 dlls.
I would like don't rebuild setup, but to make a patch containing 1-2 dlls.

What methods I can do this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, support for patches (.msp) is very limited or non-existent in Visual Studio Setup Projects. Some people [have used command-line scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33783489/87698) to create patches. You might be better off using a setup tool that officially supports patches, if you need them. [WiX](https://wixtoolset.org/) is quite popular and free, but has a steep learning curve compared to Visual Studio Setup Projects. There are other (including commercial) alternatives, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Thank you! 
It took four days to figure it out.
Maybe someone will come in handy - I posted a project for creating patches on the github.

https://github.com/andrewbutenko80/prjCreatePatch

Also I use information from [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11373/How-to-create-installation-patches-for-VS-NET-depl)

Comment: It is important that the creation of patches works correctly, the Product code for the old and new versions of the installation must be the same